# PSSessionStateBroken with start-job -credential in scheduled task

Tags: powershell, background-process, powershell-3.0, start-job

The lines below work fine from a Powershell prompt, but fail from a scheduled task.

```
$pass = gc C:\secrets\shhh.txt | convertTo-secureString
$Cred = new-object -typeName System.management.automation.psCredential -argumentlist "domain\domainUser",$pass

$path = "\\server\share\folder"
$j = start-job {gci -path $args[0]} -cred $Cred -argumentList $path | wait-job | receive-job

$body = $j | out-string
$error | out-file C:\temp\err.txt
send-mailMessage -to me@domain.tld -from server@domain.tld -subject halp -smtpserver mailserver.domain.tld -body $body
```

In c:\temp\err.txt the Windows 2008R2 Scheduled Task leaves a breadcrumb:

```
[localhost] The background process exited abnormally.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2101,PSSessionStateBroken
```

...which brings us to [this Microsoft bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/powershell/feedback/details/736114/psv3-start-jobs-running-from-scheduled-task-with-different-credentials-fail#details). The report mentions a workaround with localhost loopback remoting, which sounds kinda dirty. Should I go there?

Is there a better solution? Maybe with one of the *session cmdlets or invoke-command? The scheduled task's `Start in` value is set, but maybe the background process uses some variable in some bad way, like [so](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832434)?

No luck yet calling powershell.exe with `–version 2` or with `-command "& {bigKlugeyScriptblock}"` syntax.

**edit:** I'm trying to avoid creating a new domain account to run the task. The task can't run as `domainUser` from `$cred`, because that account should not have permissions on localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some possible work arounds how about:

1. Put alternate credentials on the scheduled task itself
2. Using the [runas](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) command to start powershell.exe as a different user
3. Using [net use](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) /user parameter to authenticate access to the network path

   ```
   [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
   [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
   ```

Comment: Thanks. 1) see edit 2) Promising. Reading up on runas /savecred and cmdkey.exe and will report back.

Comment: Work-around #1 is good enough here after all. I'm okay granting 'Log on as a batch job' to $cred in Local Security Policy, and that privilege seems to be enough to run the Scheduled Task.

Comment: ...or [should I be okay with that](http://serverfault.com/questions/494605/windows-security-can-user-read-local-files-with-only-log-on-as-a-batch-job)?

Answer (score 0):

This code allows you to run a scriptblock locally on the same server, but you must be running powershell as an administrator or you will get access denied error.

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName localhost -Credential $credential
try
{
    Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {"hello from $env:USERNAME"}
} finally {
    $s | Remove-PSSession
}
```